# Vb.net call class from inside another class

Tags: vb.net, class, oop

I have 3 Classes.

1 - araTrendClass

2 - driverClass

3 - sayfaYardimcisiClass

I called and used driverClass inside my araTrendClass.

But I want to use driverClass inside another class from inside my araTrendClass.

So, I want to call driverClass not directly.

I want to call it from inside my araTrendClass.

How can I access this class from another class?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your question could benefit from some example source code, even if its partially working. It would help others offer suggestions without needing to imagine how far you've already progressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `driverClass`  instance to the class that will use it, perhaps as a constructor argument:

```
Public Class SayfaYardimcisiClass

  Private _driverClass as DriverClass

  Public Sub New(driver As DriverClass)
    _driverClass = driver 'hold on to reference we are given
  End Sub

  Public Sub DoSomething()
    Console.WriteLine(_driverClass.Name) 'the araTrendClass code class will set it to "hello"
    _driverClass.DoSomething()
  End Sub

End Class


Public Class AraTrendClass
  Private _topLevelDriverClass as New DriverClass

  Public Sub DoThatThing()

    _topLevelDriverClass.Name = "hello"

    'give this instance of DriverClass to the new SafayaYardimcisiClass
    Dim syc as New SayfaYardimcisiClass(_topLevelDriverClass)

    syc.DoSomething() 'will print "hello"

  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: now i need pass DriverClass from SayfaYardimcisiClass to another one class how can i do this ?

Comment: I used the answer at the top , it worked.
I can pass driverClass from one class to another class , it working.
but now i need pass this to another one class too.
how i can pass this one more time ?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand - there aren't any restrictions on how many times you can share a class instance; just do the same thing again

Comment: i fixed problem :) - now everything is okey , working well :)